# controller + params_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**PROBLEM SOLVED, TY ALL!**

My Answer_controller

```
  def index

     question_id    = params[:question_id].to_i
     respondent_id  = params[:respondent_id].to_i
     @questions     = Question.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => question_id}) 
  end
```

When i put in url: `http://localhost:3000/answer/index?question_id=40` everythings ok and show me my question. Ok! But i have another table (respondents) with 3 record. And i want to insert it into my url i want url like this => `http://localhost:3000/answer/index?question_id=40&respondent_id=3`

(P.S = Relationship-table: id, question_id, repondent_id )

How can i do it? And if i enter wrong `repondent_id` (i have only 3 => 1,2,3), for example 4 it will be error

UPDATE

```
if !@questions
  flash[:error] = "No question found for gived ID: #{question_id}"
  redirect_to :action => :show_error
end
```

if i put wrong id, i get my error, everything ok, but with question_id, and i want if i write wrong id for respondent i get error too (for example: WRONG RESPONDENT_ID DUMB ASS)

Comment: I don't understand your problem completely. If you have only 3 records in respondents table then validate the params and if its wrong then set default one.

Comment: heh.. i want get following url: http://localhost:3000/answer/index?question_id=40&respondent_id=3 , but i cant,i want to know how to add respondent_id to url. http://localhost:3000/answer/index?question_id=40 <= this works perfectly!

Comment: show the way you put question_id to parameters, please

Answer (score 0):

for kishie: 
this is controller

```
 def index

    #@answers=Hash.new

    question_id             = params[:question_id].to_i
    respondent_id           = params[:respondent_id].to_i

    @questions                  = Question.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => question_id}) 
    @respondents            = Respondent.find(:first, :conditions => {:id => respondent_id})

    if !@questions
      flash[:error] = "No question found for gived ID: #{question_id}"
      redirect_to :action => :show_error
    end

    if !@respondents
      flash[:error] = "No repondent found for gived ID: #{respondent_id}"
      redirect_to :action => :show_error
    end

  end
```

this is view:

```
<% form_for :email, :url => { :controller => 'answer', :action => 'create' } do |f| %>
    <%= @questions.id %>. <%= @questions.text %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body, :rols => 10, :cols => 60 %><br />
    <%= submit_tag "Send Survey "%>
<% end %>
```

and url you can write : `http://localhost:3000/answer/index?question_id=40&respondent_id=4`